# Accept hex only input

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am trying to create an input box that only accepts Hex characters **[A-Fa-f0-9]**.

I know there are a lot of options but have found none that ticks all my checkboxes.

- Need to restrict actual user input (so characters other than A-Fa-f0-9 will NOT be allowed entry/keypress/paste

  - I know this can be done through keyup/keydown/onchange event, but I need this to be enabled globally, more elegant solution
- Another option is the input `pattern`, but this still allows user entry of 'invalid' characters, will just display later on that the validation has failed.

My thoughts:

- Top choice: If it is possible to extend the input type:

```
<input type="hex">
```

- If possible to have a vue directive for this (supposing `q-input` is my component):

```
<q-input v-hex>
```

So I created this vue directive that removes all non-hex characters and converts letters it to uppercase:

```
Vue.directive('hex', {
  update: function (el, binding) {
        console.log('Input ' + binding.value)
    
    var newVal = binding.value.replace(/[^a-fA-F0-9\n\r]+/g, '')
      console.log('New Hex Only Val = ' + newVal.toUpperCase())

    binding.value = newVal
  }
})
```

But it doesn't update the parameter passed in the v-model (parameter holding the `binding.value`).

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/keechan/nade9cy0/3/

Sample input -> expected output:

- 123abc -> 123ABC
- 12hf23dn -> 12F23D

How can I update its respective v-model parameter? Please note that this directive will be used globally so no hardcoding anywhere.

Anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: yes, if you are going to repeat this input.. instead of using `pattern` i would go with `directive`.. one alternative is to create your own component for that..

Comment: Haven't created a custom vue-directive before but it seems they always start with `v-` when applying them to a component. So your `hexonly`-directive would be used as `<q-input v-hexonly>` (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Intro)

Comment: @Rie ah yes, i have updated my description. But on the fiddle link, it is v-hex.. but still cant make it work

Comment: Hmmm. this seems to be more of a quasar-specific issue then. I mean, you did tag quasar (I just didn't see it, my bad). You could try to extend the quasar component using `Vue.extend`. An example-implementation is described here (scroll to the very bottom) https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/4572/how-to-uppercase-v-model-of-q-input/14

Answer (score 0):

```js
Vue.directive('hexonly', {
    bind(el, binding, vnode) {
        const vm = vnode.componentInstance;
        el.__unbindHexonly = vm.$watch('value', value => {
            vm.__emitValue(value.replace(/[^a-fA-F0-9\n\r]+/g, '').toUpperCase());
        }, { immediate: true });
    },
    unbind(el) {
        el.__unbindHexonly && el.__unbindHexonly();
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6bw0zvdm/

Quasar uses some deferred model update magic, thus using specific private method `__emitValue` ([source](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/blob/dev/ui/src/components/input/QInput.js#L210))

By the way, you don't need to specify directive expression (`"txt"`), `v-hexonly` will work.